# What does None = e mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know why I keep getting this or what it means. I'm trying to concatenate a string and it won't print it. I have tried different code but I still keep getting this.

This is my code:

```
    x=10
    line = (str(myLine("-")))
    A = line[0:6] + " " + "A" + " " + line[6:(x*3)]
    print (A)
```

myLine is a function that multiplies "-" by 10.

I've been changing x by the way so I don't think x is the problem.

Comment: Can you post some code that reproduces the error?

Comment: So far as I know there is nothing meant by `None = e` in Python. It's not a valid Python statement and I don't know of an error message that would say it.

Comment: @kindall, it is not a valid python statement **since version 3**, and is a _really bad idea_ in python 2 (that's why they changed None to a keyword)

Comment: It's not a valid Python statement in version 2.7 either. That's the oldest one I have installed but according to [this](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html) it became unchangeable in 2.4.

Comment: oh, I hadn't realized they made an exception for None, in python 2.7 you can do `True = False` which is a __very bad idea__ but it seems you are right about None

Comment: @tokenmaster44, I do believe the code you have provided along with `def myLine(s):return s*10` produces the output `------ A ----` so unless you can provide a _verifiable_ example your question makes no sense.

Comment: "A" is actually under a variable: Letter. However, I changed the variable Letter to "String" and I got None String...and if I change it to "34", I get None 34.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I removed myLine function and just did "-"*10. No None message shows up now.

Comment: do you mean that `myLine` was returning `None`? like, it didn't return anything?